# Transversal on Quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

A transversal on the sides $AB, BC, CD, DA$ of a quadrilateral $ABCD$ at the points $P, Q, R, S$ respectively. Prove that $\frac{AP}{PB}·\frac{BQ}{QC}·\frac{CR}{RD}·\frac{DS}{SA} = +1$

My first attempt was to prove this by using Menelaus's theorem but couldn't come to a satisfactory result. I would be highly obliged for a perfect solution to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Connect AC to intersect the transversal and apply Menelaus on ABC and ACD. What do you get?

Comment: @CalvinLin Thank you so much! I proved it using your hint.

Comment: What is a trensversal on a quadrangle? Can you write its definition?

Comment: Post an actual answer.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sure thing, do check it out!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

First, we draw a quadrilateral ABCD and draw the transversal that cuts the quadrilateral as instructed in the aforementioned question.

Next, we connect AC.

Let the point of intersection of the transversal and the line AC be T.

On applying Menelaus' theorem in $\Delta ABC$, we get:

$\frac{BQ}{QC}·\frac{TC}{TA}·\frac{AP}{PB}=-1$             (1)

Similarly, on applying Menelaus' theorem in $\Delta ADC$, we get:

$\frac{DS}{SA}·\frac{AT}{TC}·\frac{CR}{RD}=-1$             (2)

Now, Multiplying (1) and (2):

$\frac{BQ}{QC}·\frac{TC}{TA}·\frac{AP}{PB}·\frac{DS}{SA}·\frac{AT}{TC}·\frac{CR}{RD}=1$

Hence, $\frac{BQ}{QC}·\frac{AP}{PB}·\frac{DS}{SA}·\frac{CR}{RD}=+1$

Proved!

Comment: Credits to @Calvin Lin for helping me out

Comment: $\frac{TC}{TA}$ in $(2)$ is correct?

Comment: Shouldn't the product of the ratios (carefully written) be $-1$ in Menelaus's Theorem? These are ordinarily signed lengths and the order of the letters matters.

Comment: Regret the mistakes. They have been rectified.